# Запятая или тире в сложном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, бсп

*Иванов обозвал Петрова глупцом. Петров не таков(,) Иванов допустил ошибку.*

Что должно быть в скобках — запятая или тире?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, что запятая в данном контексте не подойдет. Это не просто два изъяснительных предложения в составе одного бессоюзного сложного — между ними явно чувствуется взаимозависимость. Предлагаю обратиться к [**следующему правилу**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151) (справочник Розенталя, "Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении").

> В бессоюзном сложном предложении **тире** между частями обычно ставится в тех случаях, когда основная часть высказывания (соответствующая иногда главной части сложноподчиненного предложения) содержится во второй части сложного предложения, а первая часть (соответствующая придаточной части) имеет подчиненное по смыслу значение, указывая время или условие совершения действия, о котором идет речь во второй части, иногда **причину**, уступку и т. д.
> *На улице проливной дождь — выйти невозможно* — **причина** указывается в первой части, во второй приводится следствие, вывод, что составляет основу высказывания.

Почему Иванов допустил ошибку? Потому что Петров не таков.

Итак, мой вариант пунктуации:

***Петров не таков — Иванов допустил ошибку.***